# How does one deal with multiple interviews?

Tags: interviewing

Suppose a person is getting multiple on-site interviews while working at another position. Is it acceptable to take multiple days off work to attend the on-site interviews?

Comment: That depends on how keen the person is to leave their current job.

Answer (score 3):

Your personal days and your vacation days are yours to take and you don't owe anyone an accounting as to how you spend your personal days and vacation days. However, your management definitely has a say on how you schedule your personal days and vacation days, as there is a disruption in the workflow every time someone takes time off.